# Is there a way to work around lag when attempting to interact with objects in a ScrollView

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I need to have a set of Images bring an replicate off-screen Image onto the mouse-position and be draggable.

Edited***I've found that the lag came from putting the GridLayout into a Scrollview. Unfortunately, I need to use the nested layout in a Scrollview for my application. Is there a reason why this is happening?

Edited code

```
class IconMenuItem(Image):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        if(self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)):
            self.update_touch_image(self.id, touch)
            touch.grab(self)
            return True
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is not self:
            return
        self.update_touch_image(self.id, touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is not self:
            return
        touch.ungrab(self)
        self.return_image(self.source)

    def return_image(self,source):
        drag_icons=self.parent.parent.parent.parent.draggable_icons
        for icon in drag_icons:
            if(icon.source==source):
                icon.center=self.to_window(-1000,-1000)
                return

    def update_touch_image(self, id, touch):
        drag_icons=self.parent.parent.parent.parent.draggable_icons
        for icon in drag_icons:
            if(id==icon.id):
                icon.center=self.to_window(touch.x, touch.y)
                return
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.load_icon_menu()

    def load_icon_menu(self):
        #print(self.children)
        self.draggable_icons=[]
        icon_gates=["id", "x", "y", "z", "h", "s", "t", "u", "barrier", "measure", "c", "dagger", "Debug"]
        for i in range(len(icon_gates)):
            icon=IconMenuItem(source = "images/" + icon_gates[i] + "_icon.png", allow_stretch=True, id=str(i))
            self.ids['icon_menu'].add_widget(icon)
            drag_icon=Image(source= "images/" + icon_gates[i] + "_icon.png", pos=(-1000, -1000), id=str(i))
            self.draggable_icons.append(drag_icon)
            self.ids['main_screen'].add_widget(drag_icon)

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(MainScreen(name= 'screen'))


class EXApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    EXApp().run()
```

ex.kv

```
RootWidget:


<MainScreen>:
    id:screen
    FloatLayout:
        id: main_screen
        pos_hint:  {'x': 0, 'y': 0}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba:.7,.5,.7,0.3
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 0.25, 0.7/5*5
            pos_hint:{'x': 0.7, 'y': 0.2}       

            GridLayout:
                id: icon_menu
                cols: 3
                rows: 5
                padding: 10
                spacing: 10
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba:0,0,1,0.3
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is - you have so many widgets that checking all the collisions takes a noticeable amount of time?

Comment: Also, since you mentioned it: try to post a complete example that can be run but which is as short as possible and doesn't include anything unnecessary for replicating the issue.

Comment: @inclement - yes, that is the problem. I'll try to get back to you on simplifying my example.

Comment: So with the new code, the smaller example works perfectly, it's due to the fact that I have about 400 other widgets that I create upon instantiation of my screen. Is there a way to make those images into a resizeable background?
I guess that means this is a different type of problem.

Comment: I've found out how to prevent the lag. It is due to the fact that the ScrollView also has it's own on_touch_down method that needs to be resolved before my items in the GridLayout. If I switch the ScrollView to be scroll_type: ['bars'] only, then the on touch down outside the scrollview bar is ignored and passed quickly onto the elements inside. 
Thank ya'll for your patience!

Comment: Yes, you also need to make more effective what is happening in your on_touch_move method. for example, you do drag_icons = self.parent.parent.parent.parent.draggable_icons every time, I think instead it makes sense to do it for example, only 1 time when on_touch_down fired. Also I don't think self.parent.parent.parent.parent is a good practice, you can use ids instead

Comment: @me2beats That makes a lot of sense! I have very little practice with good coding practice, so I'm really thankful for your suggestion.